# PDF preview thumbnail options?

Tags: templating, assets, pdf

I'm using the most recent Craft CMS 2.6.2791. I'd like to generate preview thumbnails for pdf assets in my templates, so I found this plugin:

https://github.com/carnesmedia/pthumb

However, following the instructions on the readme page gives a nonsense url. In my template, I have:

```
<img src="{{ craft.PThumb.thumbnail(pdf) }}">
```

If I inspect the src generated by this I see

```
http://localhost:8888/myproject/public//assets/pdfs/previews/b15c8529f2b4a9b354c5e592e84d1ac5.png
```

However, this renders as a broken image. I check my project structure and the previews directory is nowhere to be found. Am I doing something wrong or perhaps missing a step?

I'm also open to any other solutions that could generate a thumbnail from the first page of a pdf asset automatically. Thanks!

Comment: You have two forward slashes after the public folder in your URL: `public//assets/pdfs`. If you visit the image URL and remove the extra slash, does the image load?

Comment: Never used the plugin, but anything unusual showing up in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`?

Comment: the double slash doesn't seem to matter. Actually it's because I put my {{siteURL}} in front of the thumbnail expression so my img tag actually looks like `<img src="{{siteUrl}}{{ craft.PThumb.thumbnail(pdf) }}">`. When {{siteUrl}} gets interpreted, craft seems to always add a slash at the end. This doesn't really prevent the url from being loaded though, at least if you enter it in the browser url bar. And I don't see anything happen to the most recent log in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` when I make changes to this template.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking to do this on Craft 3, I used pThumb previously, but I created a plugin specifically to do this for Craft 3 - https://github.com/bymayo/craft-pdf-transform

It takes Asset PDF files and coverts them to JPEG / PNG files automatically when they are uploaded.

Or, do theres a Twig method that lets you convert the PDF to an image if the image already exists in Assets. But this can be a bit labour intensive on the server to do when a template is rendering so is only advised for small files.